# Prevent user from Enter-pressing on MESSAGE type I?

Tags: popup, abap

Is there any way to disable the enter key when a `MESSAGE TYPE I` is displayed? The users are just pressing away the note without reading it.

We want to force them to actually click the green button to confirm the message instead (Yes, I know it's dumb, but I was tasked to implement this so wcyd).

```
      SELECT SINGLE text
      FROM ZWM_MATVERMERK
      INTO lv_verm
      WHERE matnr = <lf_main>-matnr
      AND werk = <lf_main>-werks.

      IF lv_verm IS NOT INITIAL. 
      MESSAGE | Note: { lv_verm } | TYPE 'I'.
      CLEAR lv_verm.
      ENDIF.
```

Comment: What about displaying the message as popup?

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai I've already tried the POPUP_TO_CONFIRM function, but it still automatically highlights the proceed-buttons and you just need to hit enter to close the popup.

Comment: in POPU_TO_CONFIRM you can use the importing parameter DEFAULT_BUTTON to highlight another button, so the user has to explicitly click on OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function module `POPUP_TO_CONFIRM` to create a modal dialog which gives you more control than the standard `MESSAGE TYPE 'I'`.

Among others, this function module has the parameter `default_button` which decides which button is the one highlighted when the popup appears and thus will be considered clicked when the user just presses enter.

```
DATA lv_answer TYPE c.
CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_CONFIRM'
    EXPORTING
        text_question = 'Are you sure?'
        default_button = 2
    IMPORTING
        answer = lv_answer.
" lv_answer will be '1' for yes, '2' for no and 'A' for canceling the dialog.
```

If you want to make really **really** sure that the user read the message, then one option is to use `POPUP_TO_GET_ONE_VALUE` to make the user confirm that they read the message by reciting something from it.

```
DATA lv_answer TYPE c.
DATA lv_value TYPE pvarfield.

CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_GET_ONE_VALUE'
    EXPORTING
        titel = 'Safety check'
        textline1 = |This operation will affect { lv_count } items.|
        textline2 = |When you are aware of that, please enter "{ lv_count }" below:|
        valuelength = 20
    IMPORTING
        answer = lv_answer
        value1 = lv_value.

IF lv_answer = 'J' and lv_value = lv_count.
    "...proceed...
ENDIF.
```

This will look like this:

[image: Popup window]

---

By the way: There are a lot more standard function modules starting with `POPUP_*` which cover a wide variety of common use-cases for modal dialogs. Some of those can be really useful.

Comment: This worked, thank you! Note: I had to us lv_answer = 'J'